# What is the origin of the expression "alas and alack"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin

So I have looked for the origin of this expression but I want native speakers or people with English studies to answer or give their answers and thoughts on what might be the origin of this expression.

Answer (score 6):

*Alas* comes from Middle English but is still used today. It expresses sorrow or regret, for example "*alas, I cannot accept your invitation*".

*Alack* means exactly the same thing, but comes from Old French.

So, saying "alas and alack" is just a way of expressing sorrow but in an exaggerated or over-the-top manner. In modern English, it can sound quite flippant or insincere. As to its origin - a quick Google indicates that the whole phrase appears in writing as far back as the 18th century, but there doesn't seem to be a definite explanation of how the saying came about. However, deliberate tautologies are not uncommon in English - for example, "*cease and desist*", "*stuff and nonsense*", "*null and void*", "*safe and sound*", "*one and only*". Many of these are purely for emphasis.